# Deleting a Magento 2 Sitemap

Tags: magento2.2.6, sitemaps

On our Magento 2 store we have a second sitemap we need to remove. Can someone advise how we do this please?

Many thanks

Comment: check the answer please

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into **backend > Marketing > Sitemap**

Open any sitemap that you want to delete. Now you can delete that sitemap from `Delete` button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. However we already did this and the sitemaps still exist?

Comment: does your directory has enough permission for delete ?

Answer (score 0):

1. if "Delete" doesn't work and gives an error like "file can't be deleted. ... Permission denied in ..." then check your permission on the media folder. After fixing the permission it should delete without a problem.
2. go to the media folder in your terminal (ssh to the server) and delete sitemap_should_be_deleted.xml. Be careful with this and not delete something valuable)